# Import STL and smoothing, creating addon, two operations in one button?

Tags: python

I want make simple addon. 
User have one button, and this button, have two very simple operations, import stl and smooth object. Of course my button is'nt working. What I'm doing wrong ?

```
import bpy

def item_type_lst(self,context):
    types={obj.type:obj.type for obj in context.scene.objects}
    return [(obj,obj,"")for obj in types]

def item_type_obj(self,context):
    return[(obj.name,obj.name,"") for obj in context.scene.objects if obj.type==context.scene.myEnumitem]

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname="dh.simple_opt"
    bl_label="Simple Operator"

    def draw(self,context):
        bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl()
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

Thank You for Your help.

Greets

Comment: Put your operators in the `execute` method.  Use the simple operator template in _`text editor > templates > python >`_- as a guide

Comment: If I put execute method I have error in line 19 :/ I forget to write, that I'm making this addon for Blender 2.79

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's 2.79 or 2.8 in this case. As suggested before: Use the *Simple Operator* template as a guide.